# How to prevent a user to log in, but allowing to change his password?

Tags: linux

I want to have a database user on my RHEL6 server. Since a DB user is just a DB user, I don't want that user be able to login to shell. I know I can define the user as nologin but this way the user won't be able to change his/her password either.

So how can I prevent user to login, in the same time allowing his/her to change password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a quick and dirty way to do it. 
First, user should have right to login.
Then, run these commands:

```
$ sudo useradd -m -d /home/username -s /bin/bash -c "login is forbidden for this user" username -N -g users
$ chown root:users /home/username
$ chmod 555 /home/username  
$ echo "trap '' 2" >> /home/username/.bash_profile
$ echo "passwd" >> /home/username/.bash_profile
$ echo "logout" >> /home/username/.bash_profile
$ passwd username
```

Now the user 'username' can login to change the password. Then logs out right after changing the password. He/she can't do anything other than changing his/her password.
CTRL+C is also blocked.

Comment: What if the user invokes `ssh <host> rm -f .bash_profile`? My understanding is that bash does not invoke `.bash_profile` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for revealing that security hole:) I'm working on it to have a fix

Comment: Thank you @MaximYegorushkin, now it is more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IPA](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Identity_Management_Guide) for centralized user management. It allows users to change passwords even if they cannot login.